# How to get Javascript to change styles?

Tags: javascript, html, button

My JavaScript is not changing the attributes upon calling them from the "Change your style" button.  It should change all four paragraphs under the images to a different style.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  I feel as if it's just a typo somewhere.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-
to-fit=no">

<title>Week4-1.html</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../js/week4-1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homework.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="../js/week4-1.js"></script>
<!--Navigation to different links and parts of the website-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Rummage Store</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
   data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-
   controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
   navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rummage Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Unique Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Love that Ink Pen Company</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who we are</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Links</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/home.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-1.html">Week 1-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-2.html">Week 1-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-1.html">Week 2-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-2.html">Week 2-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-1.html">Week 3-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-2.html">Week 3-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-1.html">Week 4-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-2.html">Week 4-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-1.html">Week 5-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-2.html">Week 5-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-1.html">Week 6-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-2.html">Week 6-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-1.html">Week 7-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-2.html">Week 7-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-1.html">Week 8-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-2.html">Week 8-2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main">

    <!--Main jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3" style="text-align:center">Rummage Items</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Card to display a logo-->
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; color:black">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/week2-1logo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Rummage it</p>
            </div>
            <!--Button to change paragraph font-->
            <p>
            <button type="button" onclick="changeStyles();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change the Style</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--Improved columns--->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" onclick="changeStyles();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change the Paragraph Style</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_shadow home_box_gradient" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />
                <h2>Printers</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product4.jpg" alt="print" align="middle">
                <p class="week4-1_Printers">The HPSR printer has a direct feed for over 30 different types of paper.  Allowing for ultimate utilization.  It also showcases the new style of modern printers.  Multifunction printers allow for use of communication via fax.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Buy for $299.99 &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_shadow home_box_gradient" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />
                <h2>Boots</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product3.jpg" alt="boots">
                <p class="week4-1_Boots">The new rummage boot collection. Hand crafted leather for the ultimate rummaging experience.  Your feet will thank you during your next rummaging expedition! We look forward to helping you try them on. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Buy for $69.99 &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_gradient home_box_shadow" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />                 
                <h2>Lamps</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product5.jpg" alt="Lamp">
                <p class="week4-1_Lamps">Lamps are a neccesity during night time.  This lamp is hand crafted and made from the finest craftsman we could find.  You will not regret buying this lamp, adding a nice piece of decor and bringing some brigtness in your life. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="../pages/week1-2.html" role="button"> Buy for $39.99  &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_gradient home_box_shadow" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />
                <h2>Dressers</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product2.jpg" alt="Lamp">
                <p class="week4-1_Dressers">Our Dressers are one of a kind.  We have so many variations that you can rummage through and find.  Purchase on our site or come in today and take a look! Very sturdy and made with some of the best wood you can buy. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="../pages/week1-2.html" role="button"> Buy for $239.99  &raquo;</a></p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</main>



<!-- Footer Information -->





<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is my js:

```
function injectStyles(rule) {
var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '&shy;<style>' + rule + '</style>'
}).appendTo("body")
}
function changeStyles() {
// alert("Hi");
// injectStyles('p { color: red; }');
injectStyles('.week4-1_Printers { border: 10px solid black; font-weight: 
 500; color: darkblue; border-radius: 10px; }');
injectStyles('.week4-1_Boots { border:10px solid black; font-weight: 500; 
 color: darkblue; border-radius: 10px; }');
injectStyles('.week4-1_Lamps { border:10px solid black; font-weight: 500; 
 color: darkblue; border-radius: 10px;  }');
injectStyles('.week4-1_Dressers { border:10px solid black; font-weight: 500; 
color: darkblue; border-radius: 10px; }');
}
```

Comment: The paragraph with the Change the Style button should call the changeStyles function.  It does nothing each time.

Answer (score 0):

I will update the

`function injectStyles(rule) {
  $("head").append('<style>' + rule + '</style>');
}`

to append style in the head.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your issue is with the button, as the code is being executed.

Instead of writing div elements why not just change the style directly?  I changed your injectStyles function to accept two arguments: the class name of the elements you want to change and a JavaScript object that contains all the style values you want to set.  Then, I just loop through every element that matches the class name, then set the style for every node in the style definition.

(you need to go into full screen to see the snippet work)

```js
function injectStyles(className, styles) {

  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  // loop through every element
  for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    
    // loop through every style
    for(var style in styles) {
      elements[i].style[style] = styles[style];
    }

  }

}

function changeStyles() {

  injectStyles('week4-1_Printers', { "border": "10px solid black", "font-weight": "500", "color": "darkblue", "border-radius": "10px" } );
  injectStyles('week4-1_Boots', { "border": "10px solid black", "font-weight": "500", "color": "darkblue", "border-radius": "10px" } );

// injectStyles('.week4-1_Lamps { border:10px solid black; font-weight: 500;  color: darkblue; border-radius: 10px;  }');
// injectStyles('.week4-1_Dressers { border:10px solid black; font-weight: 500; color: darkblue; border-radius: 10px; }');
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-
to-fit=no">

<title>Week4-1.html</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homework.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="../js/week4-1.js"></script>
<!--Navigation to different links and parts of the website-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Rummage Store</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
   data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-
   controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
   navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rummage Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Unique Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Love that Ink Pen Company</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who we are</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Links</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/home.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-1.html">Week 1-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-2.html">Week 1-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-1.html">Week 2-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-2.html">Week 2-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-1.html">Week 3-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-2.html">Week 3-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-1.html">Week 4-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-2.html">Week 4-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-1.html">Week 5-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-2.html">Week 5-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-1.html">Week 6-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-2.html">Week 6-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-1.html">Week 7-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-2.html">Week 7-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-1.html">Week 8-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-2.html">Week 8-2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main">

    <!--Main jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3" style="text-align:center">Rummage Items</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Card to display a logo-->
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; color:black">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/week2-1logo.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Rummage it</p>
            </div>
            <!--Button to change paragraph font-->
            <p>
            <button type="button" onclick="changeStyles();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change the Style</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--Improved columns--->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" onclick="changeStyles();" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change the Paragraph Style</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_shadow home_box_gradient" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />
                <h2>Printers</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product4.jpg" alt="print" align="middle">
                <p class="week4-1_Printers">The HPSR printer has a direct feed for over 30 different types of paper.  Allowing for ultimate utilization.  It also showcases the new style of modern printers.  Multifunction printers allow for use of communication via fax.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Buy for $299.99 &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_shadow home_box_gradient" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />
                <h2>Boots</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product3.jpg" alt="boots">
                <p class="week4-1_Boots">The new rummage boot collection. Hand crafted leather for the ultimate rummaging experience.  Your feet will thank you during your next rummaging expedition! We look forward to helping you try them on. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Buy for $69.99 &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_gradient home_box_shadow" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />                 
                <h2>Lamps</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product5.jpg" alt="Lamp">
                <p class="week4-1_Lamps">Lamps are a neccesity during night time.  This lamp is hand crafted and made from the finest craftsman we could find.  You will not regret buying this lamp, adding a nice piece of decor and bringing some brigtness in your life. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="../pages/week1-2.html" role="button"> Buy for $39.99  &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 home_box_border home_box_corner home_box_gradient home_box_shadow" div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
                <hr />
                <h2>Dressers</h2>
                <img class="img-circle1" src="../images/product2.jpg" alt="Lamp">
                <p class="week4-1_Dressers">Our Dressers are one of a kind.  We have so many variations that you can rummage through and find.  Purchase on our site or come in today and take a look! Very sturdy and made with some of the best wood you can buy. </p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="../pages/week1-2.html" role="button"> Buy for $239.99  &raquo;</a></p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</main>



<!-- Footer Information -->
```

If you want to keep the styles as a string you could parse it into an array using `styles.split('delimiter')`, but defining it as a JavaScript object makes it super-easy to process.

Comment: Thank you, I still can't get the four elements to change even with the updated javascript.  I am really new to all of this.

Comment: The snippet is definitely working - I just added a second class to modify.  Are you removing the period from the start of the class name?  Take a very close look at the first two lines of changeStyles versus the two I commented out.

Comment: could it be a browser issue? I copied exactly what you have written and it won't work

Comment: Does the snippet run for you?

Comment: Yes it does, but when I try to execute it from the visual studio then load it to the browser, it doesn't work.